# R principal() get eigenvalues of factors

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis

I've done a PCA and the result looks something like this:

```
                 RC1  RC14   RC2   RC5   RC3   RC9   RC6   RC7  RC16  RC11  RC19  RC12  RC26   RC8  RC10   RC4  RC20 …
SS loadings    3.199 3.161 3.001 2.958 2.928 2.908 2.793 2.786 2.727 2.723 2.696 2.558 2.544 2.540 2.515 2.499 2.494 … 
Proportion Var 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.004 … 
Cumulative Var 0.005 0.010 0.014 0.019 0.023 0.027 0.032 0.036 0.040 0.044 0.048 0.052 0.056 0.060 0.063 0.067 0.071 …
```

As you can see the factors (RC1, RC14, etc.) aren't in the correct order.

To get the eigenvalues I can use `fit$values` and I'll get a list like this

```
  [1] 4.9880983 4.3804479 3.4831868 3.4637441 3.1826873 2.9171613 2.7109790 2.7069910 2.6505181 2.5475078 2.5339040
 [12] 2.5167436 2.4434298 2.4023438 2.3648536 2.3065183 2.2927025 2.2779793 2.2523245 2.2436222 2.2073776 2.1823970
 [23] 2.1626319 2.1487751 2.1274126 2.0963421 2.0918373 2.0728735 2.0603362 2.0470462 2.0355974 2.0202679 2.0170792
 [34] 2.0013015 1.9891380 1.9874788 …
```

Now I want the eigenvalues of those factors. The question is—because the factors are not ordered—how can I match factors and their respective eigenvalues? I guess RC1 has an eigenvalue of 4.9880983, but does RC14 have an eigenvalue of 4.3804479 or 2.4023438?

Comment: What R function are you using?

Comment: I am using the principal() function from the psych library. `fit <- principal(d_cor, nfactors=21, rotate="varimax", normalize=FALSE)`
`d_cor` is a correlation matrix.

Comment: Please someone correct me if this is wrong. Since your `principal components` are listed in order of importance, and they are a product of the `eigenvalues` and `eigenvector` components, I would assume your `eigenvalues` are in the same order as your PCs. So your 2nd `principal component` (`RC14`) should be your 2nd `eigenvalue` (`4.3804479`). If this is a factor analysis, I'm not positive about that though.

Comment: That's what I assumed as well, but I wanted to make sure if that's really the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the FactoExtra library which has a lot of great tools. It lists the eigen value beside the PC axis ID so there won't be any confusion.

> library(FactoExtra)
>
> eig.val <- get_eigenvalue(fit)
>
> eig.val[1:8,] #spits out first 8 axes.